# A task for the task jar: Passwords are being replaced by passkeys

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Google has announced that passkeys will be turned on by default.

[Passwordless by default: Make the switch to passkey](https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/passkeys-default-google-accounts/)

We might need to review [How do I recover my Google account, password, or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/88163) and other related posts.

If someone is interested in joining, please add a comment.

## Related

### Tags

- [password](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password), [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google),[gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail),[google-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-account),[google-workspace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace),[android](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android), [google-chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)